# How to undo starting hadoop as root (superuser)

Tags: hadoop

When setting up hadoop, I did not know what I was doing and I accidently ended up starting hadoop as super user.

Is there any way to fix this or is it better I remove hadoop and re set it up?

Comment: Also I am running into many issues starting up hadoop services and such because I don't own the machine, its on our lab servers.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove hadoop from root group `gpasswd -d hadoop root`
2. Check the user presence in root group `gpasswd -d root hadoop`
3. If you wanted to prevent "hadoop" from getting any admin rights, you could further check that "hadoop" is not in the sudo or admin groups
   `gpasswd -d hadoop sudo`
   `gpasswd -d Tom admin`